# MongoDB - Update with $set and $first operators

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

I'm trying to update a field with the first element of an array.

The model:

```js
{
    name: { type: ObjectId },
    names: { type: [ObjectId] }
}
```

The request:

```js
Model.updateMany({}, 
            {
                $set: {
                    name: {
                        $first: '$names',
                    },
                },
            })
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ '$first': '$names' }" (type Object) at path "name" because of "BSONTypeError"

Do you know another way to set a field with the value of the first element of an array?
Should I use aggregate instead?

Comment: Pipeline is an array, not an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update with [aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

```
Model.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      name: {
        $first: '$names',
      },
    },
  }
])
```